# SQL Select only the first occurrence according to a given field

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT:** According to @MostyMostacho in the comments below, this can not be done with plain SQL. I'll keep the question opened just in case it can be useful to someone else.

I have this table:

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | J |
+---+---+
| 4 | A |
+---+---+
| 1 | A |
+---+---+
| 6 | A |
+---+---+
| 7 | A |
+---+---+
| 3 | A |
+---+---+
| 5 | A |
+---+---+
| 3 | P |
+---+---+
| 4 | P |
+---+---+
| 1 | P |
+---+---+
| 5 | P |
+---+---+
| 6 | P |
+---+---+
| 7 | P |
+---+---+
```

And I want this result:

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | J |
+---+---+
| 4 | A |
+---+---+
| 6 | A |
+---+---+
| 7 | A |
+---+---+
| 3 | A |
+---+---+
| 5 | A |
+---+---+
```

I want to keep the first occurrence of `a` and discard the subsequent rows.

What query should I perform in order to achive that? My SQL skills are getting rusty...

Comment: Should define "first" in this context.  The ordering of the rows when returning a dataset from MySQL is not guaranteed unless there is some type of an `ORDER BY` applied.

Comment: As I just wrote in the 2nd note, the table is actually ordered.

Comment: order is conditioned by alfabetically position od column B?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry. Is it clear now?

Comment: @JoeTaras no, it isn't.

Comment: @Strawberry A set of `J`s, a set of `A`s and a set of `P`s. That table is the `UNION` of 3 queries. Just edited the question.

Comment: @jackflash If the result IS ordered then it should be possible to demonstrate the ordering criteria.

Comment: @MostyMostacho In fact, what I want is `DISTINCT A` but only the first occurrence, so I guess it is also impossible to do with plain SQL, right?

Comment: If you can tell us how it's ordered then we can tell you how to solve the problem. However, you may need to provide the *entire* query

Comment: @MostyMostacho Do not take the effort for me, my friend! I thank you bu I can do it in PHP.

Comment: @jackflash Ok, that'd be better for both of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM myTable T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 'NEXT'
   FROM myTable T2
   WHERE T2.a = T1.a
   AND T2.b > T1.a
)
```

Not exists subquery get only the last, I assume your order is conditioned by ASC value of column B

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific timestamp or otherwise monotonously increasing id column, there is no way to query into the order that rows in a table were inserted; the database engine is free to return rows in any arbitrary order it pleases, which may not be the order in which the rows went in.

Therefore, what you suggest is actually *impossible* for most RDBMS with the table schema you have provided.

---

Were you to have the following table, however:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  id   |   A   |   B   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   1   |   z   |
|   2   |   1   |   y   |
|   3   |   1   |   x   |
|   4   |   2   |   y   |
|   5   |   2   |   x   |
|   6   |   3   |   x   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

You could do:

```
SELECT a.A, a.B
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY A
) b ON b.id = a.id
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b90/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.A, a.B
FROM (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, a, b FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r  ) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, a, b FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r  )
    GROUP BY A
) b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: @MostyMostacho, that's EXACTLY what an illegal grouping does in mysql, returns first entry

Comment: Can you please post an official documentation link stating that?

Comment: @MostyMostacho you are right http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html
ocumentation says it is random. From my experience it always takes the first found record.

Comment: the query above works fine though

Comment: You're both right - although the comments section of the manual includes a reference to it!. However, you cannot be sure that it will work in future releases (although it probably will) ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry It is proven that it doesn't work now. It would be the same as saying that `select * from table` returns data sorted by PK. Try inserting and deleting random records and you'll see it is not the case.